# Adjusting LaTeX thesis template to LuaLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, luatex, templates

For my PhD thesis, I'm using the following template available at:
https://github.com/mcmanigle/OxThesis

When I compile this in TeXStudio with pdfLaTeX everything works well.
However, when I use LuaLaTeX - which I prefer, especially in order to avoid issues with special characters - I get a range of "! Undefined control sequence." errors.

Unfortunately, my knowledge of TeX is much too basic to figure out what I should change in order to make this template work with LuaLaTeX.

Any help / suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alan said the `[pdftex]` option should be removed from `graphicx` (it is best to remove that even if you are using pdftex)

Then the block starting at line 412

```
% JEM: for crazy multi character set quotes and Unicode and all
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[LGR,TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\hyphenpenalty=500
\def\longs{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont s
```

should be

```
\usepackage[greek,latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\hyphenpenalty=500
\def\longs{^^^^017F}
```

(Latin Modern is the default in  luatex and you should never use `inputenc` or `fontenc` packages with LuaTeX oe XeTeX)

(500 seems rather high for `\hyphenpenalty` but that comment would also apply if using pdftex)

Comment: Any particular reason you did not suggest `polyglossia`? It is my understanding that issues from a few years ago are no longer issues.

Comment: @RobtAll well since I'm english it doesn't make any difference, certainly babel is being much more actively updated than polyglossia currently, so unless there was a specific issue and you are using babel I see no reason to suggest changing.

Comment: I didn't look that far down the class. I've deleted my answer since this covers both.